# Is it possible to perform "tabs" in Multimarkdown?

Tags: markdown, multimarkdown

Is there a way to realize tabs in Multimarkdown syntax?

My Goal is something like:

- Item:-----------tab------->Value
- An other item:---tab--->Value
- And one item more:--->Value

I could realize that by a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4058964/641514), but this would be an overhead. I'd love it to stay a list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can type "tab" characters wherever you like.  But there is no concept of alignment outside of a table since there is no way to know whether the resulting output will be displayed in a monospace or variable-width font. And since Markdown/MultiMarkdown eat unnecessary whitespace, the extra spaces would be stripped from the resulting output.

A list is designed to display sequential data.  A table is designed to show tabular data.  It seems that you want to show tabular data, but are trying to force it into a format that wasn't designed for that purpose.

So the concise answer to your question is "No".

Comment: If you use MultiMarkdown Composer, it supports [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/), which does allow you to do what you desire, in the *source text*.  The alignment would not work with other text editors.

They two columns would *not* align in the HTML output, however.  Only in the source plain text, and only in Composer, or another text editor that supports elastic tabstops.

Answer (score 2):

> but are trying to force it into a format that wasn't designed for that purpose.

If you go back to typewriters the purpose of tabstops original where tables ;)

It is really a pity that elastic tabstops and .tsv text files (instead .csv with comma or semicolon as separator depending on region) are not common today. The easiest way to write a table is simply hitting tab. It is also the easiest way to read tabular data in columns. Only for the programmers of the first text editing programs it was easier to show every tab character simply as 4 spaces. The Elastic Tabstops feature shows consecutive lines of text with tab characters in table columns.

In a perfect world we had plain text tables everywhere easy to write and read thanks to Elastic Tabstops. Unfortunately it seems not easy to implement in existing text engines.