# markdown insert tabulator (R)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way to insert *tabulators* in R markdown code? 
I just want to show sth. like

```
attendees:  33
sick leave:  1
presenters:  5
```

Text is Markdown text, numbers are inline R code. Simply putting spaces does not work, since there is a variably spaced font.

Ideally working for both HTML and PDF output. (I work on Win-10 in RStudio)

All my searches ended up in (a) creating markdown tables (too big), or (b) how to create tabs for tabbed browsing, much more complicated. I tried \t and \t, does not work.

Comment: Is your showed example a text or a data.frame?

Comment: Text in markdown + numbers inserted by inline R code. Couldof course create a data.frame and print it by R code, but this looses the elegance of markdown.

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384746/is-it-possible-to-perform-tabs-in-multimarkdown

Comment: Thanks! No, I had missed that one. SInce Markdown does not support it, that's probably why I could not find an answer. (even if I do not concur with the concept of "sequencial data not designed for tabular output or v.v.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use either the RStudio add-in `BeautifyR` which has a nice `Beautify Table`. Got the top banner under `Tools` there is the `Add-ins` button load `BeautifyR`.

Then there is also using Kable. Look for the R packages and install: knitr::kable and kableExtra.